# Flutter: Http request works on virtual device, but doesn't on real phone

Tags: android, flutter, http

The part of my application is shown using the information which I retrieve from server's API: the problem is that everything runs well on virtual device, but when I test the app on my phone, the http request doesn't work, so I only see progress indicator, which I set in FutureBuilder.
P. S. INTERNET permission is set in "main" AndroidManifest.

Comment: please share your code!

Comment: Set permission on the other manifests.

Comment: Which AndroidMenifest.xml do you save the code inside src/main or any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was just a problem with the responding server

Answer (score 0):

If you working with HTTP files on Android 9+, you also need to add `android:usesClearTextTraffic="true"` flag in the AndroidManifest.xml